# Program ignores all the numbers after the 1st one

Tags: python-3.x

Why the program takes just the first number in the list and ignores others, making an empty list.

This happens in every function with **for** loop.

```
cars=[23.11,1531,'volvo','BMW']

  def price(CAR):

    num=[]
    strings=[]
    for i in CAR:
        if isinstance(i,float)or isinstance(i,int):
            num.append(i)
        elif isinstance(i,str):
            strings.append(i)
        else:
            pass
        return num,strings


print(price(cars))
([23.11], [])
```

Comment: I dont see an issue with the code, I just copy pasted your code in my machine and it ran perfected as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is, your `return` statement is aligned with your for loop, so it exists after the first iteration. (Though it looks aligned correctly right now, maybe the editor corrected it instinctively.)

Comment: the editor corrected that but it has to be in the same position as if and elif statement

Comment: So that's the problem. If the return statement is inside the for loop, then it will exit after the first pass. It should be aligned with the for loop.

Comment: Good to hear that it works. Remember to 'accept as answer' when your problem is solved, so that the issue is closed.